# Salvar mensagem de usuário em arquivo-texto ou no banco de dados?

Tags: php, sql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em PHP seguindo o padrão MVC(Model-View-Controller). Resolvi criar uma página de exclusão de conta para os usuários e exibir um campo de texto para que eles possam nos informar por que estão abandonando o sistema. A minha dúvida é se devo salvar essas mensagens em um arquivo-texto ou em uma tabela do banco de dados. 
Pensei também em criar uma lista com possíveis motivos de abandono do sistema e o usuário só precisaria selecionar a opção da lista compatível. 
Entretanto desta forma alternativa, eu limitaria o usuário apenas à lista que eu criei, ou seja, não saberia se ele estaria abandonando o sistema por um motivo não mencionado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bruno**, provavelmente você já esteja trabalhando com banco de dados. Neste caso, o ideal é manter tudo no banco de dados.

No HTML, você pode incluir a lista pré-definida (com `radiobox`) de motivos e também um campo (`textarea`) para escrita à próprio punho do motivo do cancelamento. No PHP, basta checar se o radiobox que veio é o `outro_motivo`, se for, então `$motivo = $_POST['textarea_do_motivo']`.

**Proposta de Modelagem de Banco de Dados**

Segue uma proposta de estrutura da tabela **`cancelamentos`** (`MySQL`):

```
CREATE TABLE `cancelamentos` (
  `id_cancelamento` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_usuario` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `data` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `motivo` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_cancelamento`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Mesmo que o usuário escolha um item (`radiobox`) da lista, este item seria salvo no campo `motivo`.